# AWS RDS Running MySQL 5.7 running on high CPU utilization with very few processes running

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

There is unusual CPU activity on an AWS RDS instance running MySQL 5.7
Server Config:
Instance class: db.m4.2xlarge
vCPU: 8
RAM: 32 GB

Despite this, the CPU utilization remains on average between 25-50%. with occasional periods of 100% utilizations, with no more than 10 active connections at a time. Any troubleshooting methods are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Enable slow query logs. Add APM to your SQL clients.

Comment: For a quick check:  SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;  

Look at the Time column. Are any queries longer than a couple of seconds?

Comment: Additional information request. 
Any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
E) complete MySQLTuner report 
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes - 
htop OR top  for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a Linux/Unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.